# Kernel and Image of the differentiation transformation $T(p(x))=\frac{dp(x)}{dx}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let T:$P_3$→$P_2$ be the differentiation transformation $T(p(x))=\frac{dp(x)}{dx}$.
>
> Find bases for the kernel and the image space of $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us see what happens to $p_3(x) = a_3x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ after derivation. You get $p'(x)=3a_3 x^2 + 2a_2 x + a_1$. Namely, the original polynomial $p_3(x)$ is spanned by $\{x^3, x^2, x, 1\}$ where the Image is spanned by $\{x^2, x, 1\}$. As such, the polynomials which derivation is $0$ are constants, thus $KerT = sp\{1 \}$. You can easily check that $\dim P_3 = \dim P_2 + \dim P_0. $

Comment: What does sp{1} denote?

Comment: $sp\{1\} : \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Bases of P3 are x$^3$, x$^2$, x, 1.

Bases of P2 are x$^2$, x, 1.

f(x$^3$)= 3x$^2$  ;    f(x$^2$)= 2x   ; f(x)=1;

Thus the base of  kernel is {1}

Base of Image is {x$^2$, x, 1}

Comment: Can't the basis of the kernel be any constant, i.e. $P_0$?

Comment: Sure it can be . It is just a practise to write 1, like we write (1,0) (0,1) as bases.